# How to print the index in selection sort

Tags: python

- How to print the index in selection sort

Code is below for selection sort

- Loop over array
- find the index of smallest element
- Swap it over

```
    def solve(A):
        l = []
        for i in range(len(A)):
            min_idx = i
            for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
                if A[min_idx] > A[j]:
                    min_idx = j
            #swap
            A[i], A[min_idx] = A[min_idx], A[i]
            l.append(A[i])
        return l
```

Code to find the index

```
for i in l:
    m.append(A.index(i))
```

Here code to find the index is not working because

- A  array is already sorted, so every time it will give index as  [0,1,2,3..]
- Do i need to do deepcopy for the operation?

Comment: You mean you want the indexes of the original unsorted array?

Comment: @Maws In that case you can put the original array in a dict and put their indices as a value. you can access those indices and make your list.

Comment: @like enumerate?

Comment: Could you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see your input, desired output and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a lot of ways. Here is one,

```py
>>> sampleList = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
>>> index_before_sorting = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(sampleList), key=lambda x:x[1])]
>>> print(index_before_sorting)
[2, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

So you can just take this and out the list comprehension in your function and that should work. let me know if it's not clear.